# TLC59116 will not drive LEDs

Tags: integrated-circuit, i2c, led-driver, texas-instruments, mbed

Having the hardest time with this [TLC59116 LED Driver](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59116.pdf) IC from Texas Instruments. I have done a crazy amount of debugging and still cannot get it to drive a single LED. I have followed all the instructions on the datasheet, as well as referenced every software library/tutorial I could find to make sure I am doing everything properly, but it still will just not drive an LED.

I have double checked the validity of the chip and can confirm it is stable.

Here is how I currently have it hooked up:

[image]

And here is my I2C code:

```
  void writeRegister(char reg, char data) {    
    char buffer[2];
    buffer[0] = reg;
    buffer[1] = data;
    i2c->write(address, buffer, 2);
  }

  writeRegister(MODE1, 0b00000000); // defaults
  writeRegister(MODE2, 0b00000000); // defaults

  writeRegister(GRPPWM, 0xFF);      
  writeRegister(GRPFREQ, 0xFF);

  writeRegister(LEDOUT0, 0b11111111); // led "fully on"
  writeRegister(LEDOUT1, 0b11111111);
  writeRegister(LEDOUT2, 0b11111111);
  writeRegister(LEDOUT3, 0b11111111);


  writeRegister(PWM0, 0xFF);   // full brightness
  writeRegister(PWM1, 0xFF);
  writeRegister(PWM2, 0xFF);
  writeRegister(PWM3, 0xFF);
  writeRegister(PWM4, 0xFF);
  writeRegister(PWM5, 0xFF);
  writeRegister(PWM6, 0xFF);
  writeRegister(PWM7, 0xFF);
```

I have tried several enumerations of this code but it makes zero difference.

Like... am I missing something integral here?

Comment: Are you sure the address is correct?

Comment: ya its `0b1100 000`

Comment: ahh ‍♂️..... for some reason the mbed I2C library wanted the 8-bit address -> `0b1100 0000`

Comment: Happens to us all. Some frameworks want 7 some want 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong I2C address. I was using the 7-bit address of `0b1100000` instead of the 8-bit address `0b11000000`...

Comment: Good. Don't forget that you can accept your own answer (maybe after a day or two, I think) to indicate that the problem is solved.